# SMO to Azure SQL using multiple threads

Tags: c#, azure, smo

I have a multithreaded service, which uses SMO to read table and column names and also may alter the database. We are currently looking into Azure and proceeded to try the code there. It has been working with SQL Server already a long time.
In Azure SQL, when using only one thread, everything works fine. When 2nd thread starts reading while 1st thread is still executing, an exception is thrown:

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String query, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql execSql, String query)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo, StatementBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult result)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorDataReader(Request req)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetInitDataReader(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ImplInitialize(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.Initialize(Boolean allProperties)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.InitializeChildObject(ObjectKeyBase key)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.GetObjectByKey(ObjectKeyBase key)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableCollection.get_Item(String name)
```

Fierce googling has not produced anything feasible, using SMO should be just fine, if you do not share anything between threads. I already updated to the new official SMO 2017 nuget package by Microsoft, it did not help. After 1st thread is finished, second operates fine so only one thread can be reading database.
All help would be greatly appreciated.

The code i use to read the DB follows:

```
  private Database GetDataBase()
    {
        //do not have to get this from DB every time on same thread.
        if (_db != null) return _db;
        //GetConnection just returns new SqlConnection
        using (var conn = _executor.GetConnection() as SqlConnection)
        {
            conn.Open();
            var sConn = new ServerConnection(conn);
            var server = new Server(sConn);
            _db = server.Databases[sConn.DatabaseName];
            _db.DefaultSchema = "dbo";

            //Problem with Azure:
            //Enumerate these to ensure immediate crash, when 2nd thread kicks in
            //and 1st thread is still executing.
            //Works fine with SQL Server
            foreach (Table t in _db.Tables)
            {
                foreach (Column c in t.Columns)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        return _db;
    }
```

Comment: It seems it is not supported in the Azure SQL. I assume Microsoft has only implemented a partial set of SMO on Azure SQL.(If i am wrong, please correct me).

Comment: I refactored the SMO part ouf of the code, so who knows, if this is still an issue.

Comment: Did you solve this? Facing the same exact problem in 2021...